# Can't ping Cisco ASA 5505 from wireless clients

Tags: networking

I can not ping ASA 5505 from any wireless client.

TWC  Internal IP (192.168.1.2):
Ext IP: DHCP

Motorola Surfboard modem SBG6782-AC. ASA 5505 (192.168.1.1):

My saved config:

```
ciscoasa# sh run
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.2(5)
!
hostname ciscoasa
domain-name smighome.local
enable password 1cph2jkQNIEXgcQi encrypted
passwd 2KFQnbNIdI.2KYOU encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.0.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp setroute
!
ftp mode passive
dns domain-lookup inside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 209.18.47.61
 name-server 209.18.47.62
 domain-name smighome.local
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
access-list out extended permit tcp any interface outside eq www
access-list out extended permit tcp any interface outside eq 3389
pager lines 24
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
static (inside,outside) tcp interface www 192.168.1.1 www netmask 255.255.255.255
access-group out in interface outside
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL
http server enable
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 10
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns 209.18.47.61 209.18.47.62
dhcpd ping_timeout 750
!
dhcpd address 192.168.1.10-192.168.1.41 inside
dhcpd dns 209.18.47.61 209.18.47.62 interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
username admin password GuTP./ua/3msOUW/ encrypted privilege 15
!
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:c7d445457ea6a169cf5b98ad0e73fc8b
: end
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure ICMP inspection on your ASA.

`policy-map global_policy`

`class inspection_default`

`inspect icmp`